# bootstrap-responsive.css is not included in the customized bootstrap version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I went through and customized (at the [bootstrap website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)) the column widths and gutter for a new website I am working on. When I download the zip file from bootstrap it does not come with the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file. If I try to load in the `bootstrap-responsive.css` that comes with the standard download it seems like it reverts back to the 12 column layout.

I was looking through the `bootstrap.css` customized file I downloaded and it looks like it contains some responsive mark-ups but not quite all of it. This made me start thinking that maybe they combine the two .css files during a custom download and the problem is actually with my code? Before I spend hours and hours going through the code with a fine tooth comb I wanted to see if its really just a combined file? Should the download from bootstrap actually be including the two .css files? Or is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: After searching for several hours it looks like I missed the obvious. Right in the documentation it says "If you've compiled Bootstrap from the Customize page, you need only include the meta tag." The meta tag is as follows <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> Just for the record I did try to answering my own questions but it looks like I don't have enough rep. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever checked on [github repo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) . You just don't have to do anything. Download customized Bootsrap on their [website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html), and now its the trickier part they have recently changed its name to bootstrap.css from bootstrap-responsive.css. So don't worry everything is same. Either you can download its uncompressed version or minified version.
Link it to your meta tag, to make style sheet persistent, set the rel attribute to "stylesheet" `<link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Some of the browsers wouldn't consider the styles without rel attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Download the full project at:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html ( Download Bootstrap source )

open the package. ZIP folder and look for the docs> asets> css file there is a: bootstrap-responsive.css

hope that helps.